# Gulp, Reactify, and Babelify not transforming together

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs, reactify

This is my gulpfile code:

```
gulp.task('react', function () {
  browserify('app/src/main.jsx')
    .transform(reactify)
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'));
});
```

Only the first transform statement runs, and therefor throws an error due to the lack of additional transform (I'm writing in ES6 and JSX w/ react).

I'm at a complete loss and would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reactify should no longer be used. You don't say what version you are on, but as of [Babel 6](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/) "preset's" are the standard way to achieve compilation.

Run the following

```
npm install save-dev babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015
```

You should also make sure Babelify is up to date. Then your Gulp config becomes

```
var babelify = require("babelify");
gulp.task('react', function () {
  browserify('app/src/main.jsx')
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'));
});
```

See the [options page](https://github.com/babel/babelify#options) for more information.

Comment: When you say reactify should no longer be used, are you talking broadly or about this particular scenario?

Comment: Babel does everything reactify does and more, and it is just as easy to setup with gulp/grunt or on its own. The OP is *already using babel*, so there is no point in also using reactify

Comment: Thanks. Got here after googling around for some solid reasons to justify one over the other above personal preference.